# How to install/start Ubuntu classic?

Tags: unity, 11.10, gnome-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

I have installed 11.10 and I understand it doesn't come with Ubuntu classic but if I really want to go back and not use Unity what options do I have?
Can someone please guide/advise me what do I have to add/install to get Ubuntu classic as an option?

Answer (score 4):

Install the package `gnome-session-fallback` then you can select "GNOME Classic" at the login screen.

Note that this is not Gnome2 but the Gnome3 fallback session. There are some differences to Gnome2, like you need to use Alt-righclick instead of just rightclick to edit the panel.
See [gnome-panel is dead, long live gnome-panel](http://www.vuntz.net/journal/post/2011/04/13/gnome-panel-is-dead,-long-live-gnome-panel!) for more about the new panel.